# DateTimePicker.MinDate Issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I want to set the minimum and maximum date on a `DateTimePicker` in `VS2015`. I want to set the minimum date to a value from my database, and the maximum date to `DateTime.Now`. I have the following code:

```
SQLiteCommand cmdForShopRegDate = new SQLiteCommand(@"select Date from [ShopRegistration]", con);
SQLiteDataAdapter AdapterShopRegDate = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdForShopRegDate);
DataTable TableShopRegDate = new DataTable();
AdapterShopRegDate.Fill(TableShopRegDate);
this.dateTimePickerStartReport.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
this.dateTimePickerStartReport.MinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TableShopRegDate.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

I am getting the following error:

> Value of '18-Jul-28 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'MinDate'. 'MinDate' must be less than MaxDate.

Comment: what happens when you are trying this code?

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving out your `SqlConnection` to connect to your database? If not and you haven't set this up then you'll need to get that done too. Once you've queried the database, assigning the values is a simplistic task.

Comment: What issues are you having with this? Do you open your connection?

Comment: Yes! SqliteConnection is ok.

Comment: Giving Run time error.......Additional information: Value of '18-Jul-28 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'MinDate'. 'MinDate' must be less than MaxDate.

Comment: simply the mindate you are parsing is further than max date.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is related to the formatting of your data. You're parsing a value of `18-Jul-28`. The issue is that this parses as `7/18/2028` which is definitely greater than `8/2/2018`. To fix this, you'll need to parse with this format:

```
yy-MMM-dd
```

Other than that, your code can also be simplified (unless you absolutely need your `DataTable`). `SqlLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in your result set and ignores all other data.

```
using (SqlLiteConnection conn = new SqlLiteConnection("put your connection string here")) {
    using (SqlLiteCommand cmd = new SqlLiteCommand("select Date from [ShopRegistration]", conn) {
        conn.Open();
        dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.ParseExact((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar(),
                                                     "yy-MMM-dd",
                                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
    }
}

dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

You'll need to add `using System.Globalization;` to your usings for access to `CultureInfo`.

***References***:

- [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Custom Date Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: same error are showing....Additional information: Value of '18-Jul-28 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'MinDate'. 'MinDate' must be less than MaxDate.

Comment: Adjusted, made the orginal answer prior to learning your issue with the format.

Comment: Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Make sure your date is in a proper format. What is your query returning?

Comment: @"select Date from [ShopRegistration]"

Comment: That's your query, not the data it is returning. When you execute your query what is returned?

Comment: it returns only one Date.   Ex.. 18-Jul-28.

Comment: Updated answer, try removing the ` hh:mm:ss tt` from the format. Since your date is only `yy-MMM-dd`.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: My code is working properly. In this case my mistake was, from where the Shop is registering. the shop register date format was [yy-MMM-dd]. i just change this format to [dd-MMM-yy]. very very Sorry for that type mistake. also i want to say thank you to all who gives there valuable time and share there knowledge.

Comment: @PrasenjitMaity Your code worked fine, yes; assuming the date retrieved was in a traditional `MM-dd-YY` format or similar (where the year is at the end). However, my answer allows you to utilize what you had previously.